# Mysql obetener singles de artistas

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

estoy intentado obtener los singles de los usuarios,pero no consigo hacerlo.Si alguien me hecha una mano lo agradecería.

Aquí dejo mi base de datos

http://prntscr.com/ifpk7f

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, toda la informacion debe estar en la pregunta (esquema de la base de datos, que querys probaste, donde esta fallando).

Answer (score 0):

Para traer todos los singles de la tabla PERSONAL que es a lo que supongo te referis a usuarios, puedes probar:

```
SELECT a.* FROM discografica.cancion a
INNER JOIN discografica.singles b ON b.idsingles = a.idsingles
INNER JOIN discografica.grupo c ON c.idgrupo = b.idgrupo 
INNER JOIN discografica.grupo_artista d ON d.idgrupo = c.idgrupo
INNER JOIN discografica.artistas e ON e.idartistas = d.idartistas
INNER JOIN discografica.gestion f ON f.idartistas = e.idartistas
INNER JOIN discografica.personal g ON g.idpersonal = f.idpersonal
```

Ahora si quieres de un usuario especifico solo agrega la cláusala WHERE:

```
SELECT a.* FROM discografica.cancion a
INNER JOIN discografica.singles b ON b.idsingles = a.idsingles
INNER JOIN discografica.grupo c ON c.idgrupo = b.idgrupo 
INNER JOIN discografica.grupo_artista d ON d.idgrupo = c.idgrupo
INNER JOIN discografica.artistas e ON e.idartistas = d.idartistas
INNER JOIN discografica.gestion f ON f.idartistas = e.idartistas
INNER JOIN discografica.personal g ON g.idpersonal = f.idpersonal
WHERE g.idpersonal = $idpersonal
```

$idpersonal (parametro con el codigo del usuario)

Comment: Error: Unknown column 'e.idpersonal' in 'on clause' Me salta ese error al intentar hacer la primera consulta

Comment: La referencia estaba mal, la correcta es f.idpersonal de la tabla gestion, puedes probar ahora.

Comment: Califica la respuesta si te sirvio. :D